# Changing content in multiple columns with a single button click

Tags: javascript, html, css

> I am trying to change multiple columns with a single button click, after a click the image should change, the title and a phrase. I am only able to apply this to the first column. I tried iterating the columns with querySelectorAll()  and searched answers in other forums.?

> Also is it possible to assign a different random image to each column with the same single button click?
> Thank you in advance!

```
const images = ['sandwich', 'cookie', 'monster', 'telegram', 'gym']
const inputName = document.getElementById('input-name');
const inputPhrase = document.getElementById('input-phrase');
const btnSubmit = document.querySelector('.input-btn'); 
const btnClr = document.querySelector('.clr-btn'); 


const row = document.querySelectorAll('.column');
const image = document.querySelector('.column img'); 
const title = document.querySelector('.name');
const phrase = document.querySelector('.phrase');

randomImage = Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length);
logoImage = images[randomImage];

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    // createLogo()
})


btnSubmit.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    row.forEach(function(col) {
        col.classList.add('change');
        image.src =  `./images/${logoImage}.png`; 
        title.textContent = inputName.value
        phrase.textContent = inputPhrase.value
    })
});
```

Comment: `const row = document.querySelectorAll('.column');` var name is confusing here ;)

Comment: correct, should be col, ill fix it.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using a variable to refer to the image/name/phrase, you should reference them by `col` and `queryselector` in each iteration.

```
btnSubmit.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    row.forEach(function(col) {
        randomImage = Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length);
        col.classList.add('change');
        col.querySelector("img").src =  './images/' + images[randomImage] + '.png'; 
        col.querySelector(".name").textContent = inputName.value
        col.querySelector(".phrase").textContent = inputPhrase.value
    })
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but I am getting an error :                                                                                                  app.js:26 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'src' of null
    at app.js:26
    at NodeList.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (app.js:24)

Comment: @Zoh I fixed it, I was referring to your image by a class when I was copying and pasting the code but its fixed now.

Comment: Thanks that was very helpful! Anyone knows if it is possible to get a different image in each col from that button click, since the image is a random choice from an array?

Comment: @Zoh I have updated my answer for random images per row.

Comment: @imavin2 Awesome, that is great, now I understand the mechanics of things.